# How to move to the selected cell in UiCollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a newbie in `Swift`, please bear with me.

I have created a `UICollectionView` that scrolls horizontally, my question is: how can you move to the selected icon programmatically?

I have already used `didSelectedPath`, whats next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` function:

> Scrolls the collection view contents until the specified item is visible.

```
 func scrollToItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath,
                atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition,
                        animated animated: Bool)
```

**Parameters**

`indexPath`

The index path of the item to scroll into view.

`scrollPosition`

An option that specifies where the item should be positioned when scrolling finishes. For a list of possible values, see `UICollectionViewScrollPosition`.

`animated`

Specify true to animate the scrolling behavior or false to adjust the scroll view’s visible content immediately.

Check [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:) class reference with more info.

Comment: thank you very much for your guidance! It seems I need to review the documentation to learn coding

Comment: @Led I'm glad to help!